# Testng Change Methode status from passed to fail

Tags: selenium, testng

In my code i catch the error that might occure and give them a `reporter.log();` which contain the problem that happened since i dont want my code to crash after one probleme found the probleme with this is that i always get Passed as a result even though my Report Log contains a failed step.

What i want is in case that `reporter.log();` gonna be written i want to change the status of the methode into failed.

The report that i write :

```
String FormatMessageError = "<font color='red'></br><img src='"+ Bad +"'/>-";
Reporter.log(FormatMessageError +" Wasnt abel to connect</font>");
```

What i tried :
I used this :

```
Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);
```

but the status stay as passed After that i tried this :

```
SoftAssert SAAjoutPanier = new SoftAssert();
SAAjoutPanier.assertEquals(ValidationOfPurchase,false,FormatMessageError +" Wasnt abel to connect</font>");
```

with : `SAAjoutPanier.assertAll();` in the end of my @test as you can imagine it didn't work

Then i tried this :

```
Throwable throwable = new Throwable("One or more tests in this group has failed");
            throwable.setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0]);
            Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().setThrowable(throwable);
```

But it gives just a message but the status it self is still passed.

Can some one help me with this probleme ty !

Answer (score 0):

MSTest has the same limitation. The solutuon I used, just throw a real error at the end.

```
throw new Exception("some test steps failed");
```

If that works, keep a list somewhere with the real errors and inserts in the error you throw.

Comment: sadly that crashes the scenario in that step what i found out the best solution is soft assert but it s realy bad that s why i was searching for another better more professional solution